# iOS: Set coredata attributes via key value coding?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm just wondering how can I do that?

i.e. I have an entity Friends and an entity Transactions. Now every Friend has several transactions. So a Friend managed object has a set like: friend.hasTransactions.

I can filter this set via:

```
NSSet *filteredSet = [self.hasTransactions filteredSetUsingPredicate:
                          [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"paidBack = %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]];
```

But how can I set for example all these attributes paidBack in the entity Transactions to YES?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would give the relationship a more appropriate name, e.g. `transactions`.

You have to iterate through them to change them:

```
for (Transaction *transaction in friend.transactions) {
   transaction.paidBack = @YES;
}
```